# How to determine the x value on the edge of the violinplot for a mean line

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I am trying to draw a mean line on violin plots, since I was not able to find a way to make sns replace the "median" line that comes from "quartiles", I decided to code so that for each case it draws on top. I am planning on drawing horizontal lines using plt.plot on the mean value (y value) of each of the three graphs I have.

I have the exact y (height) values where I want my horizontal line to be drawn, however, I am having difficulty trying to figure out the bound of each violin graph on that specific y value. I know since it is symmetric the domain is (-x, x), so I need a way to find that "x" value for me to be able to have 3 added horizontal lines which each bounded by the violin graphs that I have.

Here is my code, the x value of the `plt.plot` is `-0.37`, which is something I found by trial and error, **I want python to find that for me for a given y value.**

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [2.57e-05, 4.17e-06, -5.4e-06, -5.05e-06, 1.15e-05, -6.7e-06, 1.01e-05, 5.53e-06, 8.13e-06, 1.27e-05, 1.11e-06, -2.87e-06, -1.38e-06, -1.07e-05, -8.04e-06, 4.77e-06, 3.22e-07, 9.86e-06, 1.38e-05, 1.32e-05, -3.48e-06, -4.69e-06, 8.15e-06, 4.21e-07, 2.71e-06, 7.52e-08, 1.04e-06, -1.92e-06, -4.08e-06, 4.76e-06]

vg = sns.violinplot(data=data, inner="quartile", scale="width")
    
a = sns.pointplot(data=data, zlinestyles='-', join=False, ci=None, color='red')
        
for p in vg.lines:
    p.set_linestyle('-')
    p.set_linewidth(0.8)  # Sets the thickness of the quartile lines 
    p.set_color('white')  # Sets the color of the quartile lines 
    p.set_alpha(0.8)

for p in vg.lines[1::3]:  # these are the median lines; not means
    p.set_linestyle('-')
    p.set_linewidth(0)  # Sets the thickness of the median lines 
    p.set_color('black')  # Sets the color of the median lines 
    p.set_alpha(0.8)

# add a mean line from the edge of the violin plot
plt.plot([-0.37, 0], [np.mean(data), np.mean(data)], 'k-', lw=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Refer to the picture where I removed the median point but left the quartile lines, where I want to draw mean lines across where the blue dots are visible

[image]

And here is a picture once I draw that plt.plot with the x value I found via trial and error: For case I only

[image: The image]

Answer (score 3):

You can draw a line that is too long, and then clip it with the polygon forming the violin.

Note that `inner='quartile'` shows the 25%, 50% and 75% lines. The 50% line is also known as the median. This is similar to how [boxplots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) are usually drawn. It is rather confusing to show the mean in a too similar style. That's why seaborn (and many other libraries) prefer to show the mean as a point.

Here is some example code (note that the return value of `sns.violinplot` is an `ax`, and naming it very different makes it rather hard to find your way into matplotlib and seaborn docs and examples).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips['day'] = pd.Categorical(tips['day'])

ax = sns.violinplot(data=tips, x='day', y='total_bill', hue='day', inner='quartile', scale='width', dodge=False)
sns.pointplot(data=tips, x='day', y='total_bill', join=False, ci=None, color='yellow', ax=ax)
ax.legend_.remove()

for p in ax.lines:
    p.set_linestyle('-')
    p.set_linewidth(0.8)  # Sets the thickness of the quartile lines
    p.set_color('white')  # Sets the color of the quartile lines
    p.set_alpha(0.8)
for x, (day, violin) in enumerate(zip(tips['day'].cat.categories, ax.collections)):
    line = ax.hlines(tips[tips['day'] == day]['total_bill'].mean(), x - 0.5, x + 0.5, color='black', ls=':', lw=2)
    patch = PathPatch(violin.get_paths()[0], transform=ax.transData)
    line.set_clip_path(patch)  # clip the line by the form of the violin
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot with line for the mean]

Updated to use a list of lists of data:

```py
data = [np.random.randn(10, 7).cumsum(axis=0).ravel() for _ in range(3)]

ax = sns.violinplot(data=data, inner='quartile', scale='width', palette='Set2')
# sns.pointplot(data=data, join=False, ci=None, color='red', ax=ax) # shows the means
ax.set_xticks(range(len(data)))
ax.set_xticklabels(['I' * (k + 1) for k in range(len(data))])

for p in ax.lines:
    p.set_linestyle('-')
    p.set_linewidth(0.8)  # Sets the thickness of the quartile lines
    p.set_color('white')  # Sets the color of the quartile lines
    p.set_alpha(0.8)
for x, (data_x, violin) in enumerate(zip(data, ax.collections)):
    line = ax.hlines(np.mean(data_x), x - 0.5, x + 0.5, color='black', ls=':', lw=2)
    patch = PathPatch(violin.get_paths()[0], transform=ax.transData)
    line.set_clip_path(patch)
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot from lists, with mean line]

PS: Some further explanation about `enumerate(zip(...))`

- `for data_x in data:` would loop through the entries of the list `data`, first assigning `data[0]` to `data_x` etc.
- `for x, data_x in enumerate(data):` would loop through the entries of the list `data` and at the same time increment a variable `x` from `0` to `1` and finally to `2`.
- `for data_x, violin in zip(data, ax.collections):` would the `data_x` loop through the entries of the list `data` and simultaneously a variable `violin` through the list stored in `ax.collections` (this is where matplotlib stores the shapes of the violins)
- `for x, (data_x, violin) in enumerate(zip(data, ax.collections)): combines the enumeration with` zip`

Comment: I am confused into how I could implement this method to my code: I am working with array's so I do not really understand what the for loop: for x, (day, violin) in enumerate(zip(tips['day'].cat.categories, ax.collections)): is iterating for.  What does x, (day,violin) really stand for? and than what the enumerate(zip(..)) really be doing? Thank you for your help by the way, I have been looking every where for an answer, a little bit more help would just be wonderful!

Comment: Also when I adjust a similar formula, my python does not understand what "violin" is on the for look and scream at me.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Initially it wasn't, then I tried Jupiter and it did

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Many thanks for the additional code.  I updated it to leave out the `[:4]` in the loop, and to be more similar to the OP.